# Use Surface Pro as a digitizer with another laptop preserving pressure sensitivity

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro

I have a first generation Surface Pro (third generation Core i5 processor, 4GB RAM, Wacom touchscreen with pen).
I bought it for drawing and sketching and it works great.

The problem is that the it heats like hell and its performance is no that good with large files and multitasking.
I was wondering if there's any way to use it only as a digitizer connected to another laptop with better specs.

One approach was to use VNC or TeamViewer to remotely draw from the Surface to my laptop, but the pressure sensitivity and eraser recognition won't work at all, so this way is useless to me.

I know there are newer and better devices in the market right now (like the new surface 4) but I can't afford to buy another device right now.